# Which words never elide?

Tags: poetry, vowel, metre, elision

I know the vocative *ō* doesn't elide with a following word in Latin, though it can elide with a preceding one. For example, Catullus LXI.39:

> *dicite "o Hymenaee Hymen…"*

For metrical reasons, this has to elide as *dicit'o Hymenae'ymen*. And a quick search hasn't found any other cases where *ō* *does* elide into a following vowel.

Are there any other words which refuse to elide like this? For example, do all interjections refuse to elide into what follows them? Or is *ō* unique?

(Notably, the Greek equivalent *ὦ* **can** join into the word after it, which makes me think this exception isn't borrowed from Greek.)

Answer (score 3):

It appears this phenomenon is not unique to the *O* interjection. The *The Elements of Latin Grammar, etc* [p.175](https://books.google.com/books?id=dmliAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA175&lpg=PA175&dq=O+vae+vah+pro+elide&source=bl&ots=O1fWillqMn&sig=ACfU3U1G2E632O8Knyjv7-kMrcs4Q7x2og&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUmLGCrcvxAhXxhv0HHcyhD78Q6AEwBXoECA4QAw#v=onepage&q=O%20vae%20vah%20pro%20elide&f=false) notes:

> *Ah*, *O*, *hei*, *heu*, *pro*, *si*, *vae*, *vah*, and also most other monosyllables are seldom elided

*A Copious Latin Grammar* [p.383](https://books.google.com/books?id=6O4sAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA383&lpg=PA383&dq=O+vae+vah+pro+elide&source=bl&ots=yHHWas1I15&sig=ACfU3U35O4KXnUUUJSNO1hg7Cl4yS54NEg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiUmLGCrcvxAhXxhv0HHcyhD78Q6AEwBHoECA8QAw#v=onepage&q=O%20vae%20vah%20pro%20elide&f=false), is more restrictive in his list (and specifically mentions "interjections" rather than any monosyllabel), but he sounds more conclusive in his statement:

> The interjections O, heu, væ, io, ah, vah, proh or pro, are not elided.